# Ways of putting 6 photographs into 4 frames

Tags: combinatorics

I have to find the number of ways of putting 6 photographs in 4 frames.Considering that

`1 2 3 4` and `2 1 3 4` are different.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you solve the problem for fewer photos in fewer frames?

Comment: @EthanBolker i have answer for 4 photos which is 24,so i thought maybe finding factorial will help,but answer for 6 frames is 360.

Comment: Try 6 photographs in 1 frame, 6 photographs in 2 frames, 6 photographs in 3 frames, ...

Comment: @Henry how do i count 6 photographs in 3 frames?

Comment: ... by extending what you would do for 6 photographs in 2 frames

Comment: @Henry what if i have 20 photographs?

Comment: there are ${C_{6}^{4}}=15$ ways of choosing 4 photos, which differs by at least one photo, then every $15$ can be arrange in $4!=24$ ways, $24\cdot15=360$

Comment: @serg_1 can you please explain how you calculated `C` i don't have a degree in math

Comment: see combinations and permutations on wiki. for clarity you can compute an amount by hand.

Comment: ${\displaystyle C(n,k)={\frac {P(n,k)}{P(k,k)}}={\frac {\tfrac {n!}{(n-k)!}}{\tfrac {k!}{0!}}}={\frac {n!}{(n-k)!\,k!}}.}$ @serg_1 this formula?

Comment: yes, and for permutations is $m!$

Comment: @serg_1 thank you it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Since there are more photos than frames, choose the 4 out 6 photos that go into the frame. This can be done in $\frac{6!}{4!2!}$. Then one can permute them in $4!$ ways.( Since the order in which its put into the frames is taken into account).   So there are totally $\frac{6!}{2!}$ ways to put 6 photos in 4 frames.